# 1920*1200 screen resolution not work my webapplication

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, resolution, screen-resolution

I'm developing the **ASP.net** project. I'm using **Bootstrap framework**, My web application not fix to following resolution, display some space `20",22",23",24"` `(1600*900)`,`(1680*1050)`,`(1920*1080)`,`(1920*1200)`

[image: look at]
[image: look at this]

how can I fix it? I used some Media queries but does not work. please help me to fix it.

Thanks,

```
.wrapper {
    background-image: url(../../Img/world.jpg);
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 560px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body { 
        width: 495px; 
    }
}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body { 
        width: 495px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body { 
        width: 495px; 
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1920px){
    body { 
        width: 100%;
        height:100%; 
    }
}

.modal-footer {   border-top: 0px; }

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 345px;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.input-lg {
    height: 46px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    line-height: 1.33;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

I'm developing the **ASP.net** project. I'm using **Bootstrap framework**, My web application not fix to following resolution, display some space `20",22",23",24"` `(1600*900)`,`(1680*1050)`,`(1920*1080)`,`(1920*1200)`

[image: look at]
[image: look at this]

how can I fix it? I used some Media queries but does not work. please help me to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried adding a certain height/ `max-height` to the body?

Comment: Sir im add this but not work `body { 
    
    margin: auto;
    padding:0px;
    width: 100%;
height:100%;
}`

Comment: im try to make it , more than 2 hours, still not fix

Comment: How about this? `body {height:100vh;}`

Comment: no sir, im try, allways displayed blank space all of pages

Comment: How about reading from this article?https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ You might want to add JQuery to it http://helplogger.blogspot.sg/2013/09/how-to-make-background-image-of-blog.html

Comment: Sir this space is getting `bootsrap.min.css` following code `html {
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`